# How to create a grid for a specific area and scale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages, map-index

I have a municipal boundary with parcels that I need broken down into smaller maps to better view the parcels.  My client wants each smaller map at a scale of 1:10,000.  I plan to used data driven pages for this series of maps.  So I know I need to create a grid.  I want to use the Grid Index Features tool, my problem is that I'm unsure of what to use for my parameters. I don't have a specific number of columns or rows and I don't know how big of a polygon I want.

So how should I set up my parameters?  And is there a better way to go about doing this?

I have ArcMap 10.2.2 - Advanced

Answer (score 2):

If you want each map to be at that scale from the Grid Index tool, you need to have use page scale box checked and then under the mapscale parameter set it at 10,000.  You should have a general idea as to what the size of the polygons you require,  or you should have a general idea as to the number of polygons that are required to cover your area and you can enter that into your options as well.

[image]